# cursor keys don't work in TableView with setCellSelectionEnabled after programmatically changing the sort column

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

Either this is a bug in TableView (my config: Win7, 64bit, jdk1.8.0_60) or I'm doing it the wrong way.

If I call `setCellSelectionEnabled(true)` on a tableView to be able to select individual cells and then I call `table.getSortOrder().setAll(idColumn)` to change the sort column programmatically, the cursor keys stop working until I click the tableView with a mouse. Calling `table.getSelectionModel().select(selectedRow, selectedColumn)` also helps but it took me 2 days to find out and it doesn't seem right.

Please use the SSCCE bellow and the following steps to reproduce the problem:

1. run the class bellow
2. press cursor keys to see **they work**
3. press F2 to sort using the first name column
4. use cursor keys to see **THEY DON'T WORK** anymore
5. click some unselected cell in the tableView
6. press cursor keys to see **they work again**
7. press F1 to sort using the id
8. use cursor keys to see **THEY DON'T WORK AGAIN** anymore
9. press F3 to sort using the last name column
10. press cursor keys to see **they work again** because that's where I call `table.getSelectionModel().select(selectedRow, selectedColumn)`

Is that a bug or is it just me?

THANKS!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewTest extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> table;
    private TableColumn<Person, Integer> idColumn;
    private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
    private TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn;

    //------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(createData());

        idColumn = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        lastNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");

        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));       

        table.setOnKeyReleased(this::tableKeyEvent);

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        table.getColumns().addAll(Arrays.asList(idColumn, firstNameColumn, lastNameColumn));

        root.setCenter(table);

        primaryStage.setOnShown(windowEvent -> {
            table.getSelectionModel().select(0, idColumn);
            table.requestFocus();
        });

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    //------------------------------------------------------
    private void tableKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.F1) {
            table.getSortOrder().setAll(idColumn);
        }
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.F2) {
            table.getSortOrder().setAll(firstNameColumn);
        }
        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.F3) {
            table.getSortOrder().setAll(lastNameColumn);

            TablePosition selectedPosition = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
            int selectedRow = selectedPosition.getRow();
            TableColumn selectedColumn = selectedPosition.getTableColumn();

            table.getSelectionModel().select(selectedRow, selectedColumn);
        }
    }


    //------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------
    /* HUGE THANKS to the random name generator at: http://random-name-generator.info/random/?n=100&g=1&st=2 
       It saved my sanity! ;-) */
    private ObservableList<Person> createData() {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person(0, "Brendan", "Carter"),
            new Person(1, "Karl", "Page"),
            new Person(2, "Jane", "Zimmerman"),
            new Person(3, "Katrina", "Mcbride"),
            new Person(4, "Natalie", "Howard"),
            new Person(5, "Jeremiah", "Bishop"),
            new Person(6, "Tricia", "Norman"),
            new Person(7, "Dorothy", "Medina"),
            new Person(8, "Leslie", "Clayton"),
            new Person(9, "Ernestine", "Gibbs"),
            new Person(10, "Donald", "Fuller"),
            new Person(11, "Barbara", "Mendez"),
            new Person(12, "Jeff", "Keller"),
            new Person(13, "Zachary", "Sanchez"),
            new Person(14, "Joyce", "Payne"),
            new Person(15, "Neil", "Paul"),
            new Person(16, "Amanda", "Patton"),
            new Person(17, "Roosevelt", "Rios"),
            new Person(18, "Hazel", "Wheeler"),
            new Person(19, "Ramona", "Jensen"),
            new Person(20, "James", "Berry"));
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------
    public static class Person {
        private final IntegerProperty id;
        private final StringProperty firstName;
        private final StringProperty lastName;

        Person(Integer id, String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id", id);
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName", firstName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName", lastName);
        }

        public Integer getId() {
            return id.get();
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id.set(id);
        }

        public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id.get() + " - " + firstName.get() + " " + lastName.get();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can neither confirm nor disprove it's a bug, since the documentation has nothing to say about this. However I can identify the reason:

The `TableColumn` for the focused cell becomes `null`.

The following is a modified version of your `tableKeyEvent` method that demonstrates the issue (prints the focused column) as well as applies a workaround.

```
private void tableKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
    TableColumn refocusColumn = null;

    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.F1) {
        refocusColumn = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell().getTableColumn();
        table.getSortOrder().setAll(idColumn);
    }
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.F2) {
        refocusColumn = table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell().getTableColumn();
        table.getSortOrder().setAll(firstNameColumn);
    }
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.F3) {
        table.getSortOrder().setAll(lastNameColumn);

        TablePosition selectedPosition = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
        int selectedRow = selectedPosition.getRow();
        TableColumn selectedColumn = selectedPosition.getTableColumn();

        table.getSelectionModel().select(selectedRow, selectedColumn);
    }
    if (refocusColumn != null) {
        // print focused column for "debugging"
        System.out.println(table.getFocusModel().getFocusedCell().getTableColumn());

        // focus previously focused column again to fix issue
        table.getFocusModel().focus(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), refocusColumn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I only concentrated on the selection and missed the focus completely. Could you please point me to some explanation of the relation between the two concepts? Somehow, I can't find any good description. I've looked at Oracle's documentation but it doesn't say much. I'm not very experienced with JavaFX and don't quite understand what it's good for. I thought focus was meant for choosing a component (like a TableView) but inside the component I should use select. Am I wrong? Can I select one cell but focus another? What sense would it make?

Comment: There is a focus on the `Scene` level and one for the `TableView`. If you're working with the table, the scene focus is on the table and the table focus is on some cell. In most cases the selection and the focus of the table are the same(CTRL+arrows to change that), but there is only one focus and potentially multiple selections. The focus is used like a cursor, pressing ENTER you'll edit the focused cell not a selected one; the selection will more likely be used with a context menu or similar functionality, but of course that's up to the coder.File explorers should support a similar concepts.